# How to handle Cells containing only NaN values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am setting up a stock price prediction data set,in that while applying the following code for Ichimoku Cloud Indicator:

```
from datetime import timedelta
high_9 = df['High'].rolling(window= 9).max()
low_9 = df['Low'].rolling(window= 9).min()
df['tenkan_sen'] = (high_9 + low_9) /2

high_26 = df['High'].rolling(window= 26).max()
low_26 = df['Low'].rolling(window= 26).min()
df['kijun_sen'] = (high_26 + low_26) /2

# this is to extend the 'df' in future for 26 days
# the 'df' here is numerical indexed df
# the problem is here
last_index = df.iloc[-1:].index[0]
last_date = df['Date'].iloc[-1].date()
for i in range(26):
    df.loc[last_index+1 +i, 'Date'] = last_date + timedelta(days=i)

df['senkou_span_a'] = ((df['tenkan_sen'] + df['kijun_sen']) / 2).shift(26)

high_52 = df['High'].rolling(window= 52).max()
low_52 = df['Low'].rolling(window= 52).min()
df['senkou_span_b'] = ((high_52 + low_52) /2).shift(26)

# most charting softwares dont plot this line
df['chikou_span'] = df['Close'].shift(-26)
```

The above code works great but the problem is while extending to the next 26 time steps(rows) in 'senoku span a' and 'b' columns it turns other rest columns row's values to NaN.

So i need the help to make 'Senoku span a' & 'Senoku span b' predicted rows in my data set without making other rows vlaues to NaN.

The current output is:

```
Date      Open    High     Low   Close   Senoku span a    Senoku span b
2019-03-16 50      51       52     53      56.0               55.82
2019-03-17 NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     55.0               56.42
2019-03-18 NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     54.0               57.72
2019-03-19 NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     53.0               58.12
2019-03-20 NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     52.0               59.52
```

The expected output is:

```
Date      Open    High     Low   Close   Senoku span a    Senoku span b
2019-03-16  50      51       52     53     56.0               55.82
2019-03-17                                 55.0               56.42
2019-03-18                                 54.0               57.72
2019-03-19                                 53.0               58.12
2019-03-20                                 52.0               59.52
```

Comment: what is the expected output you want

Comment: I want the predicted columns values  in my data set without turning any other values to NaN.

Comment: df = df.fillna(''")

Comment: yes you can use df = df.fillna("") on the final Dataframe. or you can apply it on the specific columns also like df['open'] = df['open'].fillna("")

Comment: But this code makes problem for other codes to apply, while applying with other codes it shows error as : unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'

Comment: I think if i can add the predicted values to any other dataframe or variable for deep learning.

Comment: Can you provide some starting data?